# slope-up or slope-down

Tags: nouns

Could the words *slope-up* or *slope-down* be nouns?  I found them just as verbs in the dictionary, and *slope* as a noun.

But then I see sentences such as "That slope-up was amazing."  Is it correct to use that as a noun?

Comment: I think upslope & downslope would work better.

Answer (score 1):

> #### up·slope
>
> noun
>   noun: upslope; plural noun: upslopes; noun: up-slope; plural noun: up-slopes
>   */ˈəpˌslōp/*
>   1. an upward slope.
>   adverb & adjective
>   adverb: upslope; adjective: upslope; adverb: up-slope
>   */ˌəpˈslōp/*
>   1. at or toward a higher point on a slope.

Now, for downslope.

> #### down·slope
>
> */ˈdounˌslōp/*
>   noun
>   noun: downslope; plural noun: downslopes; noun: down-slope; plural noun: down-slopes
>   1. a downward slope.
>   adverb & adjective
>   adverb: downslope; adverb: down-slope
>   1. at or toward a lower point on a slope.

As adverbs and adjectives, you'd use them the same way you'd use 'upwind' or 'downwind'. As nouns you'd use them exactly like in your example. Say they just went down an awesome ski run. One skier turns to his friend and says "Dude, that downslope was awesome!"

Okay, maybe I'm stretching that a bit, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. Than these sentences from newspapers aren't correct (I put: ""), e.g. 1 This photograph shows Rosamund's Tower, the path of the moat and the "slope up" to King's Tower. 
2 Looking from the bottom of Greenhill, part of the way along the Battle Trail, you get some idea of "the slope up" which Simon de Montfort's troops had to attack.
3 Bec des Rosses as the world's best freeriders carve amazing lines between and often over the rocks on "a slope up" to 55 degrees steep. (...) There should be: upslope? Or is it the same, and option "downslope and upslope" is better?

Comment: 1) In this context "slope up" is okay, because it's serving as an idiom. Think of it in this context as "the slope leading up to King's tower". 2) In this context, you're grouping the words wrong in your quotes. The sentence specifically refers to the slope **up which** Simon's troops had to attack. Essentially, this is the slope his troops had to climb to attack. 3) In this case **a slope** is **up to** 55 degrees steep. This means that the lines the climbers climb are sloped at an angle of anywhere between 0 to 55 degrees off the ground. Very nice, varied examples. Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to add attributions (assuming you're quoting here) before a moderator deletes your answer.